# I have a Pandas timeseries dataframe that I would like to filter by a specific time on the 'timestamp' column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a few classes for backtesting trading timeseries data in DataFrame format and I would like to filter the data frame by the 'timestamp' column.

I tried this `If` statement and expected it to print "worked" to the terminal:

```
if df.set_index(date_col).at_time('09:00').reset_index():
    print("worked")
```

### And received the following KeyError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/danra/dev/pycharm_projects/Deribit/backtesting/strategies/HigherLower.py", line 86, in <module>
    HL.run_backtest()
  File "C:/Users/danra/dev/pycharm_projects/Deribit/backtesting/strategies/HigherLower.py", line 34, in run_backtest
    self.generate_signals()
  File "C:/Users/danra/dev/pycharm_projects/Deribit/backtesting/strategies/HigherLower.py", line 14, in generate_signals
    if df.set_index(date_col).at_time('09:00').reset_index():
  File "C:\Users\danra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\danra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5446, in set_index
    raise KeyError(f"None of {missing} are in the columns")
KeyError: "None of ['timestamp'] are in the columns"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have tried changing the dictionary key/values in the datamanager.py file but received the same KeyError.

These are the three modules in use.

#### backtest.py

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from backtesting.datamanager import DataManager


class BackTestSA:
    """
    backtesting class for all single asset strategies,
    columns must include the following :
    close: float
    timestamp: date
    """

    def __init__(self, csv_path, date_col, max_holding):

        self.dmgt = DataManager(csv_path, date_col)

        # trade variables
        self.open_pos = False
        self.entry_price = None
        self.direction = None
        self.target_price = None
        self.stop_price = None
        # vertical barrier variable
        self.max_holding = max_holding
        self.max_holding_limit = max_holding

        # barrier multipliers
        self.ub_mult = 1.005
        self.lb_mult = 0.995

        # special case of vertical barrier
        self.end_date = self.dmgt.df.index.values[-1]

        self.returns_series = []
        self.holding_series = []
        self.direction_series = []

    def open_long(self, price):
        """

        :param price: price we open long at
        :return: populates trade variables from constructor with relevant
        variables
        """
        self.open_pos = True
        self.direction = 1
        self.entry_price = price
        self.target_price = price * self.ub_mult
        self.stop_price = price * self.lb_mult
        self.add_zeros()

    def open_short(self, price):
        """

        :param price: price we open short at
        :return: populates trade variables from constructor with relevant
        variables
        """
        self.open_pos = True
        self.direction = -1
        self.entry_price = price
        self.target_price = price * self.lb_mult
        self.stop_price = price * self.ub_mult
        self.add_zeros()

    def reset_variables(self):
        """
        resets the variables after we close a trade
        """
        self.open_pos = False
        self.entry_price = None
        self.direction = None
        self.target_price = None
        self.stop_price = None
        self.max_holding = self.max_holding_limit

    def add_zeros(self):
        self.returns_series.append(0)
        self.holding_series.append(0)
        self.direction_series.append(0)


    def close_position(self, price):
        """

        :param price: price we are exiting trade at
        :return: appends the trade pnl to the returns series
        and resets variables
        """
        pnl = (price / self.entry_price - 1) * self.direction
        self.process_close_var(pnl)
        self.reset_variables()

    def process_close_var(self, pnl):
        self.returns_series.append(pnl)
        self.direction_series.append(self.direction)
        holding = self.max_holding_limit - self.max_holding
        self.holding_series.append(holding)

    def generate_signals(self):
        """

        use this function to make sure generate signals has been included in the child class
        """
        if 'entry' not in self.dmgt.df.columns:
            raise Exception('You have not created signals yet')

    def monitor_open_positions(self, price, timestamp):
        # check upper horizontal barrier for long positions
        if price >= self.target_price and self.direction == 1:
            self.close_position(price)
        # check lower horizontal barrier for long positions
        elif price <= self.stop_price and self.direction == 1:
            self.close_position(price)
        # check lower horizontal barrier for short positions
        elif price <= self.target_price and self.direction == -1:
            self.close_position(price)
        # check upper horizontal barrier for short positions
        elif price >= self.stop_price and self.direction == -1:
            self.close_position(price)
        # cehck special case of vertical barrier
        elif timestamp == self.end_date:
            self.close_position(price)
        # check vertical barrier
        elif self.max_holding <= 0:
            self.close_position(price)
        # if all above conditions not true, decrement max holding by 1 and
        # append a zero to returns column
        else:
            self.max_holding = self.max_holding - 1
            self.add_zeros()

    def add_trade_cols(self):
        """
        merges the new columns we created for our backtest into our dataframe,
        also resets the returns series to empty lists, incase we want to change
        the strategy heartbeat.
        """
        self.dmgt.df['returns'] = self.returns_series
        self.dmgt.df['holding'] = self.holding_series
        self.dmgt.df['direction'] = self.direction_series

        self.returns_series = []
        self.holding_series = []
        self.direction_series = []

    def run_backtest(self):
        # signals generated from child class
        self.generate_signals()

        # loop over dataframe
        for row in self.dmgt.df.itertuples():
            # if we get a long signal and do not have open position open a long
            if row.entry == 1 and self.open_pos is False:
                self.open_long(row.t_plus)
            # if we get a short position and do not have open position open a sort
            elif row.entry == -1 and self.open_pos is False:
                self.open_short(row.t_plus)
            # monitor open positions to see if any of the barriers have been touched, see function above
            elif self.open_pos:
                self.monitor_open_positions(row.close, row.Index)
            else:
                self.add_zeros()

        self.add_trade_cols()

    def show_performace(self):
        plt.style.use('ggplot')
        self.dmgt.df.returns.cumsum().plot()
        plt.title(f"Strategy results for {self.dmgt.timeframe} timeframe")
        plt.show()

    def save_backtest(self, instrument):
        """

        :param instrument: ETH, BTC for Ethereum and Bitcoin
        saves backtest to our backtests folder
        """
        strat_name = self.__class__.__name__
        tf = self.dmgt.timeframe
        self.dmgt.df.to_csv(f"../data/backtests/{strat_name}_{tf}-{instrument}.csv")
```

#### datamanager.py

```
import pandas as pd


class DataManager:

    def __init__(self, csv_path, date_col):

        self.data = pd.read_csv(csv_path, parse_dates=[date_col],
                                index_col=date_col)
        # Can use uniform to change this.
        self.data['t_plus'] = self.data.open.shift(-1)
        self.data.dropna(inplace=True)

        self.df = self.data.copy()
        self.timeframe = '1min'

    def change_resolution(self, new_timeframe):

        resample_dict = {'volume': 'sum', 'open': 'first',
                         'low': 'min', 'high': 'max',
                         'close': 'last',
                         't_plus': 'last'}

        self.df = self.data.resample(new_timeframe).agg(resample_dict)

        self.timeframe = new_timeframe
```

#### Higherlower.py

```
from backtesting.backtest import BackTestSA
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class HigherLower(BackTestSA):
    def __init__(self, csv_path, date_col, max_holding):
        super().__init__(csv_path, date_col, max_holding)

    def generate_signals(self):
        df = self.dmgt.df

        if df.set_index(date_col).at_time('09:00').reset_index():
            print("worked")
            
        df['longs'] = ((df.high > df.high.shift(1)) & (
                    df.high.shift(1) > df.high.shift(2))
                       & (df.close.shift(2) > df.high.shift(3))) * 1
        df['shorts'] = ((df.low < df.low.shift(1)) & (
                    df.low.shift(1) < df.low.shift(2))
                        & (df.close.shift(2) < df.low.shift(3))) * -1
        df['entry'] = df.shorts + df.longs
        df.dropna(inplace=True)

    def show_performace(self):
        plt.style.use('ggplot')
        self.dmgt.df.returns.cumsum().plot()
        plt.title(f"Strategy results for {self.dmgt.timeframe} timeframe")
        plt.show()

    def run_backtest(self):

        self.generate_signals()
        for row in self.dmgt.df.itertuples():
            if row.entry == 1:
                # adding logic for dymanic barriers
                if self.open_pos is False:
                    self.open_long(row.t_plus)
                else:
                    self.target_price = self.target_price * self.ub_mult
                    self.max_holding = self.max_holding + int(
                        (self.max_holding_limit / 3))
                    self.add_zeros()
            elif row.entry == -1:
                # adding logic for dymanic barriers
                if self.open_pos is False:
                    self.open_short(row.t_plus)
                else:
                    self.target_price = self.target_price * self.lb_mult
                    self.max_holding = self.max_holding + int(
                        (self.max_holding_limit / 3))
                    self.add_zeros()

            elif self.open_pos:
                self.monitor_open_positions(row.close, row.Index)
            else:
                self.add_zeros()

        self.add_trade_cols()

    def show_performace(self):
        plt.style.use('ggplot')
        self.dmgt.df.returns.cumsum().plot()
        plt.title(f"Strategy results for {self.dmgt.timeframe} timeframe")
        plt.show()

    def save_backtest(self):
        '''
        saves backtest to csv for further inspection
        '''
        strat_name = self.__class__.__name__
        tf = self.dmgt.timeframe
        self.dmgt.df.to_csv(f"../data/backtests/{strat_name}_{tf}.csv")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    csv_path = "../data/cleaned_btc.csv"
    date_col = 'timestamp'
    max_holding = 8

    HL = HigherLower(csv_path, date_col, max_holding)

    HL.dmgt.change_resolution("120min")

    HL.run_backtest()
    HL.show_performace()
    # 1049 trades with fixed stops and targets 981
    print(abs(HL.dmgt.df.direction).sum())

    # uncomment if you wish to save the backtest to folder
    HL.save_backtest()
```

#### df

```
timestamp,volume,open,low,high,close,t_plus
2018-08-13 12:00:00,1.24830802,6401.41,6390.0,6410.0,6390.0,6410.0
2018-08-13 14:00:00,325.93829282,6410.0,6215.82,6410.0,6283.5,6283.5
2018-08-13 16:00:00,16.79421917,6283.5,6102.5,6283.5,6102.5,6102.5
2018-08-13 18:00:00,247.51226331,6102.5,6102.5,6256.5,6218.5,6218.5
2018-08-13 20:00:00,0.01279864,6218.5,6218.5,6274.0,6235.0,6235.0
2018-08-13 22:00:00,0.07697618,6235.0,6200.0,6245.0,6245.0,6245.0
2018-08-14 00:00:00,9.44041963,6245.0,6000.0,6245.0,6000.0,6000.0
2018-08-14 02:00:00,3.52885021,6000.0,5878.5,6000.0,5948.0,5949.0
2018-08-14 04:00:00,33.85111565,5949.0,5934.0,5994.0,5952.0,5949.5
2018-08-14 06:00:00,1.23511251,5949.5,5912.0,6040.0,6013.5,6009.0
2018-08-14 08:00:00,0.50387477,6009.0,5981.0,6046.0,6030.0,6030.0
```

Comment: can you show your code and your data? showing the pandas code and modifying it is not usually a good idea. You will probably break something...

Comment: @David Siret Marqués added df data.

Comment: You should probably check the timestamp dtype. If it's object or string, then you might need to offer the full timestamp (2018-08-13 14:00:00) for it to recognize the row, instead of doing only (09:00). You could use regular expressions to get the rows where it has 09:00, but that's a bit more difficult

Comment: you would need to convert your `timestamp` col into datetime object: `df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have a dataframe with the data you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':['2018-08-13 12:00:00', '2018-08-13 14:00:00', '2018-08-13 16:00:00', '2018-08-13 18:00:00', '2018-08-13 20:00:00', '2018-08-13 22:00:00', '2018-08-14 00:00:00', '2018-08-14 02:00:00', '2018-08-14 04:00:00', '2018-08-14 06:00:00', '2018-08-14 08:00:00'],
                   'volume': [1.24830802, 325.938292, 16.7942191, 247.512263, 0.01279864, 0.07697618, 9.44041963, 3.52885021, 33.8511156, 1.23511251, 0.50387477],
                   'open':[6401.4, 6410.0, 6283.5, 6102.5, 6218.5, 6235.0, 6245.0, 6000.0, 5949.0, 5949.5, 6009.0],
                   'low':[6390.0, 6215.82, 6102.5, 6102.5, 6218.5, 6200.0, 6000.0, 5878.5, 5934.0, 5912.0, 5981.0],
                   'high':[6410.0, 6410.0, 6283.5, 6256.5, 6274.0, 6245.0, 6245.0, 6000.0, 5994.0, 6040.0, 6046.0],
                   'close':[6390.0, 6283.5, 6102.5, 6218.5, 6235.0, 6245.0, 6000.0, 5948.0, 5952.0, 6013.5, 6030.0],
                   't_plus':[6410.0, 6283.5, 6102.5, 6218.5, 6235.0, 6245.0, 6000.0, 5949.0, 5949.5, 6009.0, 6030.0]})
```

As you can see, the data in the timestamp column is converted to string (otherwise it throws a SyntaxError). That's the first trick we have to deal with: the timestamp column does not have a proper timestamp format, it's a string.

Then, we want to filter the rows of the dataframe based on the value of the timestamp column. We can do

```py
df['timestamp'] == '12:00'
```

which returns a Series with the truth of that statement. In this case, the result is:

```py
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
Name: timestamp, dtype: bool
```

As we can see, it's false in every row. to get it to be true in some rows, we should do:

```py
df['timestamp'] == '2018-08-13 12:00:00'
```

which returns:

```py
0      True
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
Name: timestamp, dtype: bool
```

As I just copied the first row's value into the equality, this makes sense.

If we wanted to check only by the hour, we can do 2 things:

1. Use [Regular Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), I'll leave a starting tutorial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp)
2. Separate the timestamp column into year, month, day, hour, ... For that, we need to convert the string into a datetime and then we can leverage the different methods python has for [datetime objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.year). Pandas has [pd.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the traceback, the problem is not in the `at_time()` call but on the `.set_index()` call.
This happens because when you load data you are already setting the timestamp column as the index.

```py
self.data = pd.read_csv(csv_path, parse_dates=[date_col], index_col=date_col)
```

so when you do `df.set_index(date_col)` you are getting an error (since the *timestamp* column does not exist).

The `at_time()` function is working properly:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, parse_dates=[date_col], index_col=date_col)
df.at_time("08:00:00")
```